# Java - Continuous File Logging

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java program that when executed, a log file records the end result. I tried this set of codes:

```
LogManager lm = LogManager.getLogManager();
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NetSuite SQL Log");
        lm.addLogger(logger);
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        FileHandler fh;
try {
                            fh = new FileHandler("NetSuiteSQL Sync Log.txt");
                            lm.addLogger(logger);
                            logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
                            fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
                            logger.addHandler(fh);
                            logger.log(Level.INFO, "record event");
                            fh.close();
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

and it does record but changes the date and time, like this:

```
Apr 20, 2015 4:43:38 PM com.netsuite.jdbc.main.Main main
INFO: No new record.
```

The result I'm hoping for is a log file with all previous and current logs recorded, like this:

```
 Apr 20, 2015 4:43:38 PM com.netsuite.jdbc.main.Main main
    INFO: No new record.
 Apr 20, 2015 5:04:38 PM com.netsuite.jdbc.main.Main main
    INFO: No new record.
```

Is there a set of codes that can result this kind of logging?

Comment: Can you try `fh = new FileHandler("NetSuiteSQL Sync Log.txt", true)` second arguments specifies append as true or false

Answer (score 1):

Change this `fh = new FileHandler("NetSuiteSQL Sync Log.txt")` to `fh = new FileHandler("NetSuiteSQL Sync Log.txt", true)`

As per documentation

```
public FileHandler(String pattern,
           boolean append)
```

Initialize a FileHandler to write to the given filename, with optional append. 
[FileHandler Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are overwriting the file with each restart of you program.

You might want to switch to an appending `FileHandler`:

```
fh = new FileHandler("NetSuiteSQL Sync Log.txt");
```

Documentation is [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler(java.lang.String,%20boolean))